# Intellij plugin development & Kotlin tests

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to develop an intellij plugin written in kotlin - I'm struggling to find any examples of unit tests for the plugin that are written in kotlin, or even java ones with test data that are written using gradle rather than the older dev SDK. Is anyone able to point to a demo application with unit tests? (For inspections, ideally)

Answer (score -1):

Some theory:

- [Testing in Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-tests-in-gradle.html)
- [Add test classes to a Gradle project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html#java_classes_in_gradle)
- [Testing Gradle plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/testing-gradle-plugins/)
- [Running JUnit5 tests with Gradle](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-gradle/)
- [Unit testing in Kotlin](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/unit-testing-in-kotlin-js/3943) and [kotlin.test library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/index.html)
- [Using Gradle with Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

Code samples:

- Article on [running Kotlin Unit tests with Gradle](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/running-kotlin-tests-with-gradle/)
- A [tutorial on building apps with Spring Boot and Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/#_testing_with_junit_5) with a section on testing with Junit5
- Custom [Gradle plugin example](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-create-plugin)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for, I want to know specifically for running tests on intellij plugins https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/testing_plugins/testing_plugins.html

Comment: Plugins from Community edition (source available on [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins)) contain plenty of tests as examples.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-plugins/) may be helpful as well.

Comment: So the article is specifically for writing custom languages, which is slightly different. The plugins for the community edition are writing plugins for the dev toolkit and not gradle as far as I can tell

Answer (score -1):

These come out of the box now if you use the template: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template

Here's one of the tests in Kotlin:

```
package org.jetbrains.plugins.template

import com.intellij.ide.highlighter.XmlFileType
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile
import com.intellij.testFramework.TestDataPath
import com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.BasePlatformTestCase
import com.intellij.util.PsiErrorElementUtil

class MyPluginTest : BasePlatformTestCase() {

    fun testXMLFile() {
        val psiFile = myFixture.configureByText(XmlFileType.INSTANCE, "<foo>bar</foo>")
        val xmlFile = assertInstanceOf(psiFile, XmlFile::class.java)

        assertFalse(PsiErrorElementUtil.hasErrors(project, xmlFile.virtualFile))

        assertNotNull(xmlFile.rootTag)

        xmlFile.rootTag?.let {
            assertEquals("foo", it.name)
            assertEquals("bar", it.value.text)
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin documentation also provides more relevant info for testing: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/writing-tests.html

Also, here are some unit tests written in Java for the JUnit IntelliJ plugin https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/junit/test/com/intellij/execution/junit/JUnitDetectionTest.java

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)